# SQL: High score progression by time

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, window-functions

Given a list of scores achieved in a game and the times at which they occurred, I'd like to retrieve a list of each score that was the highest when it was achieved and the time at which it did so: essentially, a high score progression. Consider this table (ordered by timestamp, with each score that was better than all previous scores marked with an asterisk):

| Score | Timestamp | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5* | 00:12 2022-08-09 |  |
| 6* | 01:15 2022-08-09 |  |
| 2 | 01:30 2022-08-09 | worse than current high score of 6, so no asterisk |
| 10* | 02:01 2022-08-09 |  |
| 7 | 03:45 2022-08-09 | worse than current high score of 10 |
| 12* | 03:50 2022-08-09 |  |
| 1* | 00:05 2022-08-10 | note different day! |
| 6* | 01:01 2022-08-10 |  |

I'd like a query which returns only the asterisked scores (that is: only the score that was better than all previous scores), for a particular day, with their associated timestamp. So, if I run the query for 2022-08-09, the results should be:

| Best Score | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 00:12 |
| 6 | 01:15 |
| 10 | 02:01 |
| 12 | 03:50 |

If this requires dialect-specific SQL, then the database engine in question is SQLite.

Comment: Is this: `00:12 2022-08-09` the actual format of the timestamps?

Comment: I put the timestamps time-first to make the table clearer, but didn't mention that; they're stored as proper timestamps in the actual DB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your timestamps have the proper format `YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM`, you can use `MAX()` window function to check if the current score in every row is the current high score:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, Score = MAX(Score) OVER (ORDER BY Timestamp) flag
  FROM tablename
  WHERE date(Timestamp) = '2022-08-09'
)
SELECT Score, time(Timestamp) Timestamp, Notes
FROM cte
WHERE flag;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=0bdd5f2c68afcc0062e7221fc67b591e).